# Could not load assembly, DLL missing in bin/release/net6.0/bin

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am trying to test a .NET 6 function app on azure but I am consistently getting "Could not load xyz assembly" error during runtime.

I saw that the assembly is present in bin/release/net6.0 but not in bin/release/net6.0/bin which I think is causing the issue.

I have added this to the csproj file as well -
I saw that the assembly is present in bin/release/net6.0 but not in bin/release/net6.0/bin which I think is causing the issue.

I have added this to the csproj file as well -

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I am using visual studio 2022.

Is there any way of having all the DLLs in bin/release/net6.0/bin folder? Any MS Build arguments which might help?
I am trying to avoid a script for this.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the DLLs should be in bin/Release/net6.0/bin?  Typically MSBuild does not build libraries into that path; the usual structure for bin folders is bin/$(Configuration)/$(TargetFramework), which in your case resolves to bin/Release/net6.0.  I suggest posting more info and context for the runtime error into your question, because the extra /bin folder feels like the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0):

As @Sean Skelly mentioned, the package DLL's will be available in bin/Debug/.net 6.0.

I have created a simple Http Azure function and all the DLL's are available in the bin/Debug/.net 6.0 as shown below:
[image]

> getting "Could not load xyz assembly" error during runtime.

- This happens if any of the the dependency is missing or cannot be loaded in the application.
- Check if the package is included in the project and also installed on the machine where the application is running.
- It also happens mostly when the package version is incorrect or incompatible with the application.
- Try downgrade or upgrading the package version which is compatible to the application.

---

*I tried using an assembly which version is not compatible with my project (.net 6.0)*

[image]

***and I was getting the same error.***

[image]

***Later, I degraded the package version and it worked.***

[image]

[image]